# Phase reversal of light using polarizer

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, maxwell-equations

I have 5 polarizers in series. The first polarizer is vertical. The second polarizer makes an angle of 45 degrees from the first polarizer in a clockwise sense. The third polarizer makes an angle of 45 degrees from the second polarizer in a clockwise sense and so on. The fifth polarizer will again be vertical.
My question is if I pass a vertically polarized light through the system then would its phase be reversed?
Consider time between zero and half of the time period. During this time period, the positive electric field will be rotated by 45 degrees by the second, third and fourth polarizer. Hence, it would still be vertical but negative.
Similarly, the negative part of the EM wave would be rotated until it becomes positive.
Is it correct to say that the phase of light is shifted by pi?
The maximum value of electric and magnetic field will obviously drop due to polarization. I am concerned about the phase of the light

Comment: it will be very difficult to di this experiment with totally coherent light. and the length of coherence will probably be smaller than the length of the experiment.  yo do not really turn anything around, you just take a different component.

Comment: @trula Can we do this for radio waves? They have a larger wavelength.

Comment: "Phase be reversed" compared to **what**?  Five vertically aligned polarizers?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch with respect to initial wave. I mean to ask would the positive part of the wave become negative and vice-versa.

Comment: "With respect to initial wave" does not make much sense.  The polarizers will shift the phase even if all aligned in parallel, depending on their thickness/refractive index.   The only meaningful comparsion is relative to a different alignment of the same polarizers.  (Or you need to specify the properties of the polarizers in detail.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the phase will be shifted by pi. Light passing through a polarizer at 45 degrees does have its polarization rotated by 45 degrees.

Comment: Suppose at time t = half of time period, I somehow instantaneously rotate the polarizers such that all the polarizers are now vertical. In this case, the positive part of the wave will become negative. The negative part of the wave will remain negative and will have a greater electric field. Is such a wave possible?

Comment: I think you are talking about a poor method for having a half-wave rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

What you have rediscovered is something called [geometric phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase). It is indeed possible to modulate the phase of light by playing with the polarization of the light. Nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Suppose that after half the time period, I rotate all the polarizers such that they are all vertical. Before this rotation, the positive part of the electric field of EM wave will phase shift to pi. But the negative part of the wave will remain negative as I have changed the polarization to vertical. Hence the wave would be always negative. Can this be possible? I know that it is impossible but where am I going wrong?